# how to handle error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, recursion

I possessed an error when displaying the data to the grid of text links that come from the results of the recursive looping.

when I debug, the message appears: 
"Troubleshooting Tips: 
the make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion. "

and this method recursive looping with me:

```
private void LevelControl(string parID)
    {
        DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select PositionCode,PositionName,Parent from Position where Parent = '" + parID + "'");          
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var Parent = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            var Child = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
            lnk = new HyperLink();
            lnk.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            lnk.ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            lnk.NavigateUrl = "Tree03.aspx?parParent=" + Parent + "&parChild= " + Child + "";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] != null)
            {
                parID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
                LevelControl(parID);
            }
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }
    }
```

then what should I do to solve this problem? 
What should be added to the code in the method?

Comment: What is the base case for your recursion i.e. for what value of `parID` can you directly evaluate without recursively calling the method?

Comment: Your code as written will result in infinite recursion. First time in, you take row 0 column 2, then you call the method again.  Second call you take row 0 column 2, call the method again, rinse, repeat.  You have no conditions where you will stop the recursion.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use parametrized queries, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you map the fields from the query wrongly to your controls. Just look at the indices.
In the query:

```
0 PositionCode
1 PositionName
2 Parent
```

In the code below:

```
0 var Parent = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
1 lnk.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
2 var Child = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
```

See: you mixed up Parent and Child, and consequently run the same query over and over again.